# How to add a HTTPS inbound rule other than 443 in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I added an Inbound custom TCP rule(port:8000) on AWS EC2. But I can't make a HTTPS API call through this port. HTTP does.
Is there anything i missed? Please help me to findout

Comment: what is your call? can you show your code?

Comment: Do you mean you can make an http call on port 8000 but not an https call on port 8000 (the same port)?

Comment: What CIDR did you add to the inbound rule?  Are you sure this is the rule associated with the EC2 instance in question?  Is this attached to a public subnet with an Internet Gateway?

Comment: Yes.@Celine Aussourd

Comment: I have created this EC2 instance on AWS for my machine learning prediction model.The call is made like this `http://<ip>:8000/predict`.That gives the result. But I need `https://<ip>:8000/predict` that didn't work for me

Comment: What kind of application is yours? Is it hosted on tomcat? How your SSL certificate is configured?

Comment: OK, that needs to be configured at your web server level (you can for example redirect http connection to https). What are you using Apache, Nginx... ?